# Java program to print a character which is available only one time in the string

Tags: java, arrays, string, search

I am trying to print a character from a string which occurs only one time in the string. Here is the code I am using, but it is showing the answer always as H.

How can I fix this?

```
class StringRepeat {

    static int i,j;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "How are How";
        outer:for(i=0;i<=s1.length(); i++)
        {
            inner:for(j=1;j<s1.length(); j++)
            {
              if (s1.charAt(i) != s1.charAt(j))
                break outer;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s1.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have several answer and a few should answer your problem. Please mark the one you chose as your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can solve this in 2 ways - brute force (using arrays) and a bit more intelligently (using maps).

### Brute force way

For every character in the input string check if it is the same as some other character:

```
public void uniqueCharsBruteForce(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        char candidate = input.charAt(i);
        if (!contains(input, candidate, i)) {
            System.out.println(candidate);
        }
    }
}

private boolean contains(String input, char candidate, int skipIndex) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        if (i == skipIndex) {
            continue;
        }
        if (candidate == input.charAt(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Code is simple but very slow, so use only for short strings. Time complexity is `O(n^2)`.

### Using maps

As you iterate through the input, count how many times each character appears. At the end, print only those who appear once only:

```
public void uniqueCharsBetter(String input) {
    Map<Character, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        Character key = Character.valueOf(input.charAt(i));
        occurences.put(key, occurences.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
    }
    occurences.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        if (entry.getValue().intValue() == 1) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        }
    });
}
```

This can be optimized further but it's possible this is enough for your requirements. Time complexity is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String s = inputString.toLowerCase();

boolean[] characters = new boolean[26];
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    characters[i] = true;

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    if(characters[s.charAt(i) - 'a'])
    {
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        characters[s.charAt(i) - 'a'] = false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. I have assumed that u treat lowercase and uppercase as same else u can modify accordingly

Comment: This doesn't even solve the problem.

Comment: will you please modify my code?

Comment: @TheJavaGuy-IvanMilosavljević  can u please elaborate to why it wont work and  it is the best strategy for this kind of questions keeping time complexity in mind

Comment: @AviralAhuja This prints every character in the input string once, regardless of how many times they occur in string. The problem was to print only characters which appear exactely once.

Comment: @TheJavaGuy-IvanMilosavljević read it again.... once a character is encountered it prints the character and changes the index to false and only prints a character if index is initially true

Comment: @AviralAhuja while you code does work, it does not solve the given problem. If a character is repeated more than once, it should not print at all. Your code prints the character once regardless of the number of appearances of the character in the string..

Comment: @AviralAhuja I will try to rephrase in pseudocode. The OP needs a code which does this: `if (characterAppearsOnlyOnce) print character`. But your code does this `print every character once`.

Comment: @TheJavaGuy-IvanMilosavljević okii i got the problem,thanks for the clearification though

Answer (score 0):

1. This will give an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if no unique
   char is found:

   ```
   outer:for(i=0;i<=s1.length(); i++)
   ```

   replace it with

   ```
   int i = 0;
   outer: for(;i<s1.length(); i++)
   ```
2. There's no need for an inner label, and you need to start the search
   from 0, not 1, so replace

   ```
   inner:for(j=1;j<s1.length(); j++)
   ```

   with

   ```
   for(int j=0;j<s1.length(); j++)
   ```
3. You have your test inverted. If the characters at `i` and `j` are
   the same, you need to continuue with the outer loop. Also, you need to
   make sure you don't compare when `i==j`. So your test changes from:

   ```
   if (s1.charAt(i) != s1.charAt(j))
     break outer;
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (i!=j && s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j))
     continue outer;
   ```
4. If the inner for loop terminates, i.e. gets to the end of the
   string, then the character at `i` is unique, so we need to break out
   of the outer loop.
5. When you exit the outer loop you need to determine if you found a unique element, which will be the case if `i < s1.length()`.

Putting this all together we get:

```
String s1= "How are How";
int i = 0;
outer: for(;i<s1.length(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<s1.length(); j++)
    {
      if (i!=j && s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j))
       continue outer;
    }
    break;
}
if(i<s1.length()) System.out.println(s1.charAt(i));
```

Here a link to the code ([IDEOne](https://www.ideone.com/glKbxF)).

Comment: it is not showing any output...No compile time error. Program terminates after its execution after its run.

Comment: Really, it prints `a` when I run it. I've added a link to the code on IDEOne so you can run it there.

Comment: Thank you very much....My problem is solved now.

Comment: could u plz tell me how the outer for loop is working. I have not seen this kind of for loop ever.

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle I think the issue is not that it does not print out `a`, which is does, it is that it only prints out `a`, and not the rest of the characters that only appear once.

Answer (score 0):

This will print out every character that appears only once in the text.

```
final String s1 = "How are How";
outer:for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++)
    {
        if(s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j) && i != j)
        {
            continue outer;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s1.charAt(i);
}
```